# Question wrongly closed as opinion based

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopen-closed, recommendation-questions

I believe this question was wrongly closed

[Linter for spring boot properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77828082/linter-for-spring-boot-properties-files)

> We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations.

This question can certainly be answered with facts. Just name a tool X that does what the question asks.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

So I've edited my question accordingly. I've removed this line:

```
Are there any static analysis tools for properties files that can help with tasks listed below?
```

And now it's

```
How could I do the following on each build:
```

So I'm "describing the problem" now.

I think this is not improving my question in any way. The answer will be some kind of static-analysis tool anyway.

How is my question different from those with high number of upvotes? I'd even argue it's more specific that 2 of the 3.

- [Dead code identification (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321241/dead-code-identification-c)
- [How can I analyze Python code to identify problematic areas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100298/how-can-i-analyze-python-code-to-identify-problematic-areas)
- [What's the current state of static analysis tools for Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617713/whats-the-current-state-of-static-analysis-tools-for-scala)

Comment: "*This question can certainly be answered with facts. Just name a tool X that does what the question asks.*" -- then perhaps you're right, it should not have been closed as "primarily opinion based". But shouldn't it perhaps then be closed as "seeking tools or libraries or other resources"? Also, it appears to be asking multiple questions at one time, suggesting that it may need more focus.

Comment: If it's not a recommendation for a tool, I'd suggest the question needs more focus. Choose your poison, but they both result in closure.

Comment: The closure reason is unclear at best. It tells me to "Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations." It doesn't say I can't ask about libraries

Comment: "So I've edited my question accordingly." You missed the title, which still asks about a linter to do what you want.

Comment: "*The closure reason is unclear at best. It tells me to "Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations." It doesn't say I can't ask about libraries*" -- You're focusing on the incorrect close reason, I'm afraid. Instead, review the [help] links, especially the subsections on asking a question.

Comment: @JakubBochenski "It doesn't say I can't ask about libraries" That’s what the [tour], [ask] and related material already told you.

Comment: But also, beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention. This may or may not be attention that you desire.

Comment: Asking for suggestions for a library falls under the "and more", @JakubBochenski . It is unrealistic to expect the closure reason to provide an exhaustive list; that would most certainly enable "rules lawyers" to abuse the system.

Comment: My main point is that the reasons for closing are unclear, obtuse and didn't t lead to substantially better question in this instance. The wording in the guides is vague.

Comment: Even *if* you aren't looking for recommendations (now), as I stated earlier the question ***is*** too broad (as it currently stands). We (the community) don't reopen questions just to close it with a different reason. Make sure that the question is on-topic for the guidelines of the site.

Comment: If only we had this, like, staging area where one can post a prospective question and have it reviewed/fixed prior to postinf

Comment: (Unfortunately) the OP would not have arrived at such a place, @KevinB ; as a user of their reputation they are *assumed* to know the expectations of the site better.

Comment: @ThomA I don't understand why is it to broad. Should I ask for every bullet in separate question? That seems silly

Comment: In short: yes. You may find that the answers come to you as a result as you learn from the answers you receive to a *specific* question.

Comment: A "How to" question although fine needs to be appropriately scoped, you're still thinking of it as a resource request (which as mentioned is off-topic) which is why that question seems fine to you. But as a how to question it is very broad.

Comment: Let's put it a different way: say you ask someone for recommendations on a mechanic, however they don't know one. As a result you ask them how to change the oil in your car, check the spark plugs, and inspect the timing belt (because that's what you wanted the mechanic to do). You're not asking for a mechanic now, sure, but that's 3 different problems. That's they're all related to your car, and you want them all done at the same time is irrelevant.

Comment: Almost every "my question was closed as seeking off-site resources; I don't think it does that" question on Meta seems more or less the same to me. [For example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426757).

Comment: "How is my question different from those with high number of upvotes? I'd even argue it's more specific that 2 of the 3." Yours is different in that it wasn't asked many years ago, before we had any real collective understanding of how the site is supposed to work. Thanks for helping identify questions that should have been closed. It looks like they have been now.

Comment: @JakubBochenski *"Should I ask for every bullet in separate question?"* - if the bullets are separate questions, yes. Even if they are not it might still be better to then not put them in a bullet list. Bullet lists look like unfocused ("too broad") questions. And as you have already experienced - people close fast, not well. So you have to try and not put red herrings in your questions to prevent people from drawing the wrong conclusion based on what they see. I wish it was still a decade and a half ago and people gave themselves the time to read between the lines, but... it's 2024 instead.

Answer (score 9):

The question is not closed as opinion-based. It's closed as 'seeking recommendation for off-site resources'.

> This question can certainly be answered with facts. Just name a tool X that does what the question asks.

Yeah, asking for tool suggestions is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You want our sister site, [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour), instead.

Comment: It tells me to "Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations." not to "Ask the question on another site". Am I the only one who see a problem with that?

Comment: @JakubBochenski the closure doesn't recommend specific sites automatically since those sites have guidance of their own on what is on-topic. if you do ask your question on Software Recommendations please read their help center pages first.

Comment: @JakubBochenski No, you're not alone. In fact most of the Meta community has spoken out about the issues with the close vote banners and what their wording choice is. Unfortunately that is under the control of SO _employees_. If Meta had its way, there'd be more close reasons, they'd be simpler, and they'd point you to far better outcomes (in many cases, like this one, you can't 'edit the question' to fix it... the question is _fundamentally_ not allowed on the site). All of that does not change the fact that your question is off-topic here, though, and should be asked somewhere else.

Comment: I already accepted that its off topic. Just wanted to point out this is extremely bad experience for user

Comment: BTW @TylerH the quide isn't much help either. I assume that's also off-limits to meta?

Comment: @JakubBochenski What is "the quide" in your previous comment? I don't know this word.

Comment: @TylerH I mean the guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: @JakubBochenski Not sure what you mean by 'off-limits to Meta'. If you mean can Meta edit it, no the community can't. Elected moderators _might_ be able to.. I'm not sure which help center pages they can edit, and the ones they can edit I think they're limited to only part of the page.